# How do I replace string or open string head in RYOBI 40V-X Expand-it String Trimmer?

Tags: tools, tool-maintenance, string-trimmer

I bought this [cordless trimmer](https://www.ryobitools.com/products/details/578) about a month ago and was happy with it. However, I didn't realize the string head dispense the internal string from tapping down when operating. I tried to dispense the string manually by pushing and twisting the red and grey part of the string head. And by accident, I rotated the grey part enough to suck all the string into the string head instead (opposite of what I want to do).

I have consulted the [user manual](https://manuals.ttigroupna.com/system/files/8354/original/RY40002_720_trilingual.pdf?2014) and YouTube videos, none shows me how to replace the string for the current trimmer, or show me how to open up the string head to replace the string manually. Please advise.

Comment: Great! Thanks I thought it must twist off but couldn't git it to twist, I gave it a couple of squirts of PB Blast and it came right off easy peasy. I found it easier to pull all the string out and start from scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are a bit tricky at first, but once you get the hang of it, and get a feel for them, they can save you tons of time. It's not super easy to understand from a step by step guide, but I'll try. Once you do it, it becomes fairly simple (like riding a bike).

1. Look for tabs on either side of the head. If there are tabs, push both in while pulling away, the take the cap off the head. If there are no tabs, it's a screw on cap. Take the head in both hands, and hold the base still while you turn the cap the opposite direction from how you reel in string.
2. Once the cap is off, lift the spool straight up and out of the head.
3. Completely unravel the string. Then center the spool in the middle of the string.
4. feed each end of the string though their dispenser holes in the head, and pull it through.
5. Place the spool back inside the head, and pull any loose string out of the head. Pull both ends together to make sure it's still even.
6. Push the cap back on until it clicks, or screw it back on.
7. Hold the base of the head steady and wind the feeder to coil the string back up. This time, stop before the string is pulled inside the heads.